# Error Matching query does not exist Django

Tags: python, django, web

I wanted to consult about a question I have, in my system I want this view to give me the products selected by their primary key that would be id, this is done with the form that is in a toggle window

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4iUI.png)

**views.py**

```
def add(request):

    cart = get_or_create_cart(request)
    productos = Producto.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('producto_id'))

    cart.productos.add(productos)

    return render(request, 'carts/add.html', {
        'productos': productos
    })
```

**Models.py**

```
class Cart(models.Model):

    cart_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    productos = models.ManyToManyField(Producto)
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cart_id
```

**HTML**

```
{% csrf_token %}
<form action="{% url 'Carts:add' %}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="producto_id" value="{{ producto.id }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Agregar al carrito</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Post code / errors as _text_ formatted as _code_ not images. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also you are making a GET request not a POST request. One issue might be your url pattern might be lacking a trailing slash causing a redirect which changes your POST request to a GET one.

Answer (score 0):

Your request method is GET. In the view, try using `request.GET.get(arg)` instead of POST.

PS You can set the second argument to empty, which is `request.GET.get('arg', None)` or `request.GET.get('arg', ' ')`. Also, try to use [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) instead of get().

Comment: Still says the image error